# How to re open EntityManager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

I have a relation between two classes, Product and Size. I added a try-catch block that would deactive the size instead of removing it if it is user somewhere else (eg: any old command with this specific product size, throwing a `ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException`)

my code is as below:

```php
$size = $sizeRepository->find($id);
$em = $doctrine->getManager();
try {
    $em->remove($size);
    $em->flush();
} catch (ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException $e) {
    $size->setActive(false);
    $em->persist($size);
    $em->flush();
}
```

It does catch the exception, though the entity manager is "closed" : `The EntityManager is closed.` is thrown.
I can't find a way to "open it back".

Does anyone has any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

```php
$doctrine->resetManager();
$size = $sizeRepository->find($id);
$em = $doctrine->getManager();
```

though you have to fetch all your objects again.